# Problems posting Event profile pictures to page javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Okay so I am working with the Facebook Graph API using the javascript API. I have been working on creating events on user's pages, not their profiles and I have that working fine. However, when i try to upload the profile picture with the event, the event creates successfully but there is no picture for it.

I have tried a number of solutions but have yet to find one that works.

Here is what I have currently:

```
 function SubmitEvent(descrip, name, start,end, line1, city, state, zip, lat, lon,path)

    {
           var eventMsg = document.getElementById('event-msg');

            var myJsonEvent = {
                "name": name,
                "description": descrip,
                "start_time": start,
                "end_time": end,
                "location": city + ", " + state,
                "venue": {
                    "street": line1,
                    "city": city,
                    "state": state,
                    "country": "United States",
                    "latitude": lat,
                    "longitude": lon
                },
                "privacy": "OPEN",
                "picture": 
            "http://stage.localruckus.com/Content/Uploads/Thumbnails/Eddie%20Delahunt_card_
                          84dc116b-f7e5-477b-b0bb-60ecdbe41955.jpg"

            };

            var select = document.getElementById("facebook-page-select");
            var pageId = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
            var res;
            FB.api(pageId, 'post', myJsonEvent, function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                if (result.id == undefined) {
                    eventMsg.innerHTML = 'There was a problem creating the event, please 
                          try  again. Error: '+result.message;
                }
                res = result.id;
                eventMsg.innerHTML = 'Event posted id: ' + result.id;
                eventId = result.id;
                postPicture(path);

            });


    }

    function postPicture(path) {
        var cookie = eventId;
        var token = getCookie('access');
        if (cookie != null && cookie != undefined && token != null && token != undefined) {
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "https://graph.facebook.com/" + cookie,
                data: {
                    message: "Event picture",
                    url:
            "http://stage.localruckus.com/Content/Uploads/Thumbnails/Eddie%20Delahunt_card_
                         84dc116b-f7e5-477b-b0bb-60ecdbe41955.jpg",
                    access_token: token,
                    format: "json"
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Picture posted successfully");
                } 
        });

     }
    }
```

Neither the postPicture method or the supplying the path to the image with the event creation api call seem to work, although i do not get any errors or anything like that.

I have spent a lot of time on google, SO , and the facebook documentation but have yet to find an answer. I found this little snippet in the facebook docs:

---

picture

Read

Issuing an HTTP GET request to /EVENT_ID/picture returns an HTTP 302 redirect to URL of the event's profile picture.

Create/Update

You can add a profile picture to an event by issuing an HTTP POST request to /EVENT_ID/picture with the create_event permission for an admin of the event and the following parameter:

Parameter    Description     Type    Required

source   Picture content    multipart/form-data  yes

Returns true if the request is successful.

Delete

You can delete an event's profile picture by issuing an HTTP DELETE request to ?EVENT_ID/picture with the create_event permission for an admin of the event.

Returns true if the request is successful.

---

But i have yet to find the mysterious "source" parameter or how to create/post multi-part form data when the data doesnt come from a form.

Can somebody help me out? I would really appreciate any help you could give me.

Comment: NOTE in the docs i did not see where can add a picture to the event create, if all else fails try to update or create the picture after the event has been created.

Answer (score 2):

BUG:  there is currently 2 bugs related to this issue.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/459815400713534

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/339792622758072

---

Have you tried url encode the link to the picture?  I believe that when it is posted from a form, the form encodes the url.  Since you are not using a form to post, you will have to encode yourself.

```
picurl = encodeURIComponent('http://stage.localruckus.com/Content/Uploads/Thumbnails/Eddie%20Delahunt_card_
                         84dc116b-f7e5-477b-b0bb-60ecdbe41955.jpg');
```

tested here http://jsfiddle.net/ShawnsSpace/e7E4c/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you for answering my question. I have not had a chance to try this out yet, but I plan on doing that today and I will let you know if this is the solution.

Comment: sorry, i did test this and was unable to upload the pic.  I found from the docs that we have to add or edit the picture after the event has been created.  That also failed in graph api explorer, i will edit in link to bug if found or another solution.